# Can I move a report from Contact Reports to My Reports?

Tags: civireport

I have 5 reports in Contact Reports which I meant to have in My Reports. Is there a way to move these to My Reports?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the report you want to add to your "My Reports." Click on the Access tab at the far right. Check the box beside "Add to my reports? That should do it for you.

[image]